# Roscore over ssh

Tags: ros, ssh, roscore, remote-roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am able to do `$ roscore` and everything is fine (also launching launch files) but when I try: `$ ssh user@machine roscore`
there is a problem, it says that

> bash: roscore: command not found

I am hydro. What could be the reason of this?

Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210800/roscore-over-ssh/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most likely the user `user` on the `machine` system has not properly setup their ROS environment. Even if you have sourced the appropriate `setup.bash` files in your local terminal, once you are ssh'ed into a remote machine, the environment on that system does not inherit anything from the launching terminal. Try ssh'ing into the machine, then sourcing the appropriate `setup.bash` file, and then run `roscore`.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-06-12**:
Thanks, the superuser of my computer wasn't able to do `roscore` :)